# Vaadin Flow 23 - Grid. How to select multiple row programmatically?

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have list of class "Devices" with attributes: name, ip, username and
I am display this list in grid.

Now I wolud like to programmatically select one or more objects (row in grid) of class Devices after
list of Devices objects are displayed in grid.

How I can do this ?

I saw article
"Vaadin Flow Grid. How to select one row programmatically?"
but it describes select for one row
so it is why decided to create new topic.

I wolud like to programmatically select one or more objects (row in grid) of class Devices after
list of Devices objects are displayed in grid.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grid.asMultiSelect()`.

```
grid.asMultiSelect().setValue(rows);
```

Here `rows` is for example of type `Set<Devices>`

Comment: It works, mean, I see in list of selected Devices that I have programmatically added Devices, but on grid (GUI) I do not have marked (check mark) them.
It is some another way to achieve it?

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with object identity.

Comment: In My project I have TextArea field nad grid.
In grid I have list of Devices.
When I selecting device in grid this device will apear in TextArea (this I have done).
And now I need opposite story, mean when I paste some device in TextArea I want to have selected this device in grid.